# How to append multiple data arrays into one varibale of xarray dataset?

Tags: python, numpy, python-xarray, rasterio

i am new in this field and i need a small help.
i just want to know that, what is the best way to append multiple data arrays in a variable of a xarray dataset?
each data array has a different time and value but has the same x,y coordinates same as dataset.
i tried `ds[variable_name] = da` but it works only for the first data array .
i want to create a function that gets data arrays and put them into one variable of the dataset and updating the time dimension of the dataset.
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way for doing that is first to convert data arrays to datasets separately then merge datasets together (using `xr.merge`).
Hope it helps the others.